# Integration identity.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, contour-integration

could you help me with the following problem please:

Verify the following identity $\displaystyle \iint_{\partial{W}} f \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\hat{n}}} \,dS=\iiint_{W} \left \| \nabla f \right \| ^2\,dx\,dy\,dz$ if $f$ is harmonic

My main question is, what do you mean $\displaystyle \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\hat{n}}}$ or if the problem is badly posed, thank you very much in advance

Comment: $\partial f/\partial n$ is the "normal derivative": the rate of change in the normal direction.  If $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit normal to the surface $\partial W$, then $\partial f /\partial n = \nabla f \cdot \mathbf{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the divergence theorem and using $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}=\hat n\cdot \nabla f$, we assert that

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{\partial W}f\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}\,dS&=\int_W \nabla \cdot (f\nabla f)\,dV\\\\
&=\int_W (\nabla f\cdot \nabla f+f\nabla^2 f)\,dV\tag1
\end{align}$$

Since $f$ is harmonic, $\nabla^2f=0$.  Using the notation $\nabla f\cdot \nabla f=||\nabla f||^2$ in $(1)$, we find that

$$\oint_{\partial W}f\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}\,dS=\int_V ||\nabla f||^2\,dV$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Is $\nabla^2$ the Laplacian? :0

Comment: Yes, it is the Laplacian.